# Can not access memory in the .bss section, but gdb 'info files' shows the address is in range

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb, bus-error

I have a binary that generates a `Bus error (core dumped)` message. When I run it under the debugger (`gdb`) it fails to access a memory location in the `.bss` section.

```
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0x0000000000412275 in ?? ()
```

The code at this location is:

```
  41226f:       0f 8f 33 ff ff ff       jg     4121a8 
  412275:       8b 35 51 b5 22 00       mov    0x22b551(%rip),%esi        # 63d7cc 
  41227b:       85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
```

So its trying to access memory at location `0x63d7cc` which is clearly within the `.bss` section: `0x63c4e0 - 0x63d7e0`.

`gdb` (along with /proc/$pid/maps) shows this memory as mapped:

```
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 16533
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
            0x400000           0x43a000    0x3a000        0x0 /somepath/someapp
            0x639000           0x63e000     0x5000    0x39000 /somepath/someapp
            0x63e000           0x65f000    0x21000        0x0 [heap]
```

```
(gdb) info files
Symbols from "/somepath/someapp".
...
        0x0000000000639c80 - 0x000000000063c498 is .data
        0x000000000063c4e0 - 0x000000000063d7e0 is .bss
```

Both examination of ELF sections:

```
% readelf -S someapp
...
  [24] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000639c80  00039c80
       0000000000002818  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [25] .bss              NOBITS           000000000063c4e0  0003c498
       0000000000001300  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [26] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0003c498
       000000000000000c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
...
```

and Segments shows this memory as mapped:

```
% readelf -l someapp
...
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000003976c 0x000000000003976c  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000039770 0x0000000000639770 0x0000000000639770
                 0x0000000000004070 0x0000000000004070  RW     200000
...
```

But `gdb` is unable to access it (and thus why the app fails). Interestingly `gdb` is able to access `.bss` memory up and until `0x63d000`:

```
(gdb) x 0x63d7cc
0x63d7cc:       Cannot access memory at address 0x63d7cc
(gdb) x 0x63cff8
0x63cff8:       0x00000000
(gdb) x 0x63cffc
0x63cffc:       0x00000000
(gdb) x 0x63cffd
0x63cffd:       Cannot access memory at address 0x63d000
```

The questions are:

What could be preventing this access? 

What other methods are available to examine runtime memory access permissions?

What else could modify the access rights of a running process?

Comment: Maybe tell us a little about how you build the app and what platform this is. It would be great if you tried to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), odds are you'll find the mistake yourself by trying to create it.

Comment: Core file and executable probably do not match.

Comment: Is this on a desktop/server platform, or on an embedded system? If an embedded system, are you using a tested, verified BSP from a board supplier, or is it home-brew?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately MCVE is not an option, I'm not using the core file, and its a desktop x86-64 system. Were doing binary file manipulation. All the data is correct, but I've run out of places to look and the data I'm seeing indicates that address should be accessible, but its not. The app actually does partially run, a number of other apps run fine after our manipulation. For some reason this last part of the .bss memory is not accessible and I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 3):

> The code at this location is:

The `.bss` is not normally executable, so likely that is why you are getting `SIGBUS` when trying to jump to it.

Your `readelf` output shows `RW` flags (note lack of `E`xecutable flag) as well.

You'll need to `mprotect` that section to add execute permissions first.

Note that some environments, such as `SELinux`, prohibit memory mappings with `RWE`, and that changing the mapping to `R-E` will cause the program to not be able to write into its (normally writable) global data. This is why putting executable code into `.bss` is probably not among the best ideas.